# Shrinking images to fit the browser window?

Tags: browser, adjustable

I was just wondering if anyone could help me. I'm creating a full width layout website, and I would like it to adjust with the browser window as it is expanded/contracted, aka everything will shrink a little and move over when the user pulls their window in/ will go back to normal when the user pulls it back out.

Say I have a grid of three 300px images, all lined up in a row, and I want them to just shrink a little, and stay in the row format when pulled in. How would I achieve this?

I'm not even sure where to start...

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In HTML when you add your  add width="20%", height="20%" for example this will expand or shrink your text according to the size of the screen.